# Graph API showing SharePoint Site Size

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'll try to get the used space of every site in our SharePoint Online. I'm using this http GET Request `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getSharePointSiteUsageDetail(period='D90')` and actually I receive the details but in a way, i dont really understand and I cant find a hint in any documentation.

the output:

```
siteId                   : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
siteUrl                  : 8F2E90AC78Exxxxx0AF934FCC592DBE3
ownerDisplayName         : DCD2C718FE1xxxxx79E22CCBD3B38E33
ownerPrincipalName       : F9B995E81F5xxxxx55C234F314A94216
```

I don't really get it, what kind of strings the 'SiteUrl', 'ownerDisplayName' and 'ownerPrincipalName' are but thats not as problematic as the missing 'siteid'.

Could this caused by wrong permission of the Graph application?
But the application has it's needed permissions (according to M$ documentation)
Reports.Read.All
beside this it also has:
Sites.Read.All

I've also tried to raise the permissions even higher with
Sites.FullControll.All
Sites.Manage.All
but this didn't helped either.

Can anybody help me out?
Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default reports are **anonymized** with GUID instead of real names. As a Microsoft 365 administrator you can choose to get the real values:

`admin.microsoft.com > Settings > Org settings > Services > Reports`

https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/Settings/Services/:/Settings/L1/Reports

**Uncheck** `Display concealed user, group, and site names in all reports` and click on `Save`

[image: Reports settings]

[image: Display names]